# How I can restore SQL Server database from mdf?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I work in SQL Server 2008 R2 and want to restore the old MSDB file. There are some very important data inside the MSDB file.

```
CREATE DATABASE DMSDBData
ON ( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DMSDBData.mdf' )
LOG ON ( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DMSDBLog.ldf')
GO
```

This script did not help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask